# How can I get Values between two data A-Z then 0-9

Tags: vb.net

## Example1

- 1st input(TEXTBOX): SAMPLEA
- 2nd input(TEXTBOX): SAMPLEG

output should show range in between two data's(BUTTON):

> SAMPLEB
> SAMPLEC
> SAMPLED
> SAMPLEE
> SAMPLEF

## Example2

- 1st input(TEXTBOX): SAMZ
- 2nd input(TEXTBOX): SAM9

output should show range in between two data's(BUTTON):

> SAM1
> SAM2
> SAM3
> SAM4
> SAM5
> SAM6
> SAM7
> SAM8

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are we supposed to write the solution for you? This can be done by few lines within `for` loop or hundreds of lines of sophisticated templated, rule based text processing engine...

Comment: Give me a Code which will give me a guide

Comment: This is not portal for "Give me a code". This is portal for "I have tried to do this that way but this and that makes me trouble...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim tb1 As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim tb2 As String = TextBox2.Text
        Dim cb As String = ""

        While (tb1 <> tb2)
            Dim temp As String = tb1.Substring(0, tb1.Length - 1)
            Dim temp1 As Char = tb1(tb1.Length - 1)

            If AscW(UCase(temp1)) >= 48 And AscW(UCase(temp1)) < 90 Then
                temp1 = ChrW(AscW(UCase(temp1)) + 1)
            ElseIf AscW(UCase(temp1)) >= 90 Then
                temp1 = ChrW(AscW(UCase(temp1)) - 42)
            End If
            tb1 = temp & temp1
            If tb1 <> tb2 Then
                cb += tb1 & " "
            End If
        End While
        MessageBox.Show(cb)
    End Sub
End Class
```

This should be what you want. Go figure on how you want to make it on your String position.

Comment: Yeah your code basis is at the end of the character what if in first or ther place character, example S1S to S8S output should be S2S, S3S,S4S,S5S,S6S,S7S,.

Comment: I also try this sx to s5 your output is s. s/ s1 s2 s3 s4 the output should be sy sz s1 s2 s3 s4.

Comment: @user3736185 for you to figure out ;) This is just a guide for you and the hardest concept of lexical is there. There will be some problem when there is only 1 character but well it's for you to solve. Like you said - "Give me a Code which will give me a guide"

Comment: @user3736185 and i just fixed the sx to s5 issue. I got the wrong UTF table.

Comment: just like in excel when you pull the value